# Is constructor mandatory in a JavaScript class?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am reading about JavaScript class from the [Mozilla documentation section of 'Class body and method definitions'](https://developer.mozilla.org/my/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#Class_body_and_method_definitions). Under the Constructor section, it states that

> The constructor method is a special method for creating and initializing an object created with a class. There can only be one special method with the name "constructor" in a class. A SyntaxError will be thrown if the class contains more than one occurrence of a constructor method.
>   A constructor can use the super keyword to call the constructor of the super class.

From the statement above, I can confirm that we can't have more than one constructor. But it does not mention whether a constructor is mandatory in a class declaration/expression in JavaScript.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You should just write a class without a constructor and see if it works :)

From the [`same docs`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/constructor)

> As stated, if you do not specify a constructor method a default constructor is used. For base classes the default constructor is:

```
constructor() {}
```

> For derived classes, the default constructor is:

```
constructor(...args) {
  super(...args);
}
```

Comment: Yes, however JavaScript is very easy to test yourself and my learning improved drastically when I realised I could just try myself whilst reading on the internet. So encouragement to try yourself is always useful. Press f12 in a browser for example.

Answer (score 10):

No, It is not necessary.  By default constructor is defined as :

```
constructor() {}
```

For inheritance we use this constructor to call super class as :

```
constructor() {
    super.call()
}
```